# Text Background Color Changing Collapses after many loops in C++! Why?

Tags: c++, windows, terminal

After running this code I noticed that if the loops are more than a specific number the Background Coloring Collapses.Somebody knows why ?
Code is in C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

This is the coloring function TextColor(parameter 1 ,parameter 2)
the function takes as parameters 
integer numbers from 0-15 and 128
first parameter is for fontcolor and
second parameter is for background color

```
#include <Windows.h>
#define BLACK 0
#define BLUE 1
#define GREEN 2
#define CYAN 3
#define RED 4
#define MAGENTA 5
#define BROWN 6
#define LIGHTGREY 7
#define DARKGREY 8
#define LIGHTBLUE 9
#define LIGHTGREEN 10
#define LIGHTCYAN 11
#define LIGHTRED 12
#define LIGHTMAGENTA 13
#define YELLOW 14
#define WHITE 15
#define BLINK 128
HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
void TextColor(int fontcolor, int backgroundcolor)
{
int color_attribute;
color_attribute = backgroundcolor;
color_attribute = _rotl(color_attribute, 4) | fontcolor;
SetConsoleTextAttribute(screen, color_attribute);
}
```

//the main program for testing the coloring function

```
int main()
{


int counter = 1;
while(counter<=50)
{ 

    TextColor(0, 15);
    int i = 0, j;
    while (i <= 5)
    {
        j = 1;
        while (j <= 28)
        {
            cout << " ";
            j++;
        }
        cout << endl;
        i++;
    }
    TextColor(15, 0);
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    counter++;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

[New image only 1 textbackground color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3bwm.png)

Comment: You are mixing two output mechanisms that do not know about each other. `cout` probably does not use WriteConsole and even if it did, it probably does not coordinate its buffering with SetConsoleTextAttribute. Try flushing the `cout` buffer before changing the color.

Comment: Nope! Nothing happens :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this line:

```
TextColor(0, counter%20);
```

If the only valid colors are between 0-15, What exactly did you expect to happen when the `counter%20` expression evaluates to something between 16-19?

Comment: That's not an issue.Anyway if more than 15 is entered as a parameter the the function mods it on its own .**The problem is not there**. 
Try to do it with only one color. Then try to make the iteration times less and again more.. It seems that a memory thing is happening but I cant find out why. *Give it a try ;)*

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "Collapses".  I'm not entirely sure what you meant.

Comment: Also, I did compile your code and it seems to work fine.  But maybe I don't exactly know what the problem is to look for it.  It's the "Collapses" thing that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Well the program creates " counter " times " i x j " colored boxes.
After many iterations the colored boxes are not boxes anymore.
The background Coloring gets out of control and does as it pleases .haha
I dont really know how that thing is called ,sorry for not being so clear.

Comment: Why don't you post a picture of what you mean?  Because it looks fine when I run it on my machine.

Comment: I'm still not unconvinced that passing values between 16-19 isn't impacting this.  Because that will cause your code to set that DBCS leading byte flag thing.  And that could easily put your console out of whack.

Comment: added a pic with only one textbackground color

Comment: It seems that you block your UI thread, it has no time to process drawing events then.

Comment: what should I do about that ?